# Display 5 stars for adding ratings instead of radio buttons

Tags: magento

default magento will display the ratings as below image

[image]

but i want to change like [this](http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-j5-6-new-2016-edition/write-review/ITMEGMRNZQJCPFG9?pid=MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z&otracker=review_write_bottom) :

[image]

i am using default magento code

**form.phtml** [app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/form.phtml]

```
<?php if( $this->getRatings() && $this->getRatings()->getSize()): ?>
                <h4><?php echo $this->__('Your Rating') ?> <em class="required"></em></h4>
                <span id="input-message-box"></span>
                <table class="data-table review-summary-table ratings" id="product-review-table">
                    <col width="1" />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="rating-box">
                                    <span class="rating-number">1</span>
                                    <span class="rating nobr" style="width:20%;"><?php echo $this->__('1 star') ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="rating-box">
                                    <span class="rating-number">2</span>
                                    <span class="rating nobr" style="width:40%;"><?php echo $this->__('2 star') ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="rating-box">
                                    <span class="rating-number">3</span>
                                    <span class="rating nobr" style="width:60%;"><?php echo $this->__('3 star') ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="rating-box">
                                    <span class="rating-number">4</span>
                                    <span class="rating nobr" style="width:80%;"><?php echo $this->__('4 star') ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="rating-box">
                                    <span class="rating-number">5</span>
                                    <span class="rating nobr" style="width:100%;"><?php echo $this->__('5 star') ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($this->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></th>
                        <?php foreach ($_rating->getOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <td class="value"><label for="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>"><input type="radio" name="ratings[<?php echo $_rating->getId() ?>]" id="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>" value="<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" class="radio" /></label></td>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="hidden" name="validate_rating" class="validate-rating" value="" />
                <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-review-table')</script>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

please help me to find solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you not style the radio buttons, so they look just like the stars?

Comment: did you checked @martin answer ?

Comment: @aximus can you please post an answer with code.

Comment: @PankajPareek i followed below solution, now is displaying like this : `http://prntscr.com/bpsz73` but i can not able to select `staars` , you can check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/vintage-retro-bicycle-background-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) & than click on `Add review` tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently dealt with it and my code looks something like this:

**form.phtml**

```
<?php foreach ($this->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>: </th>
        <?php foreach ($_rating->getOptions() as $_option): ?>
            <td class="value">
                <label for="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>">
                    <input type="radio" name="ratings[<?php echo $_rating->getId() ?>]" id="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>" value="<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" class="radio" />
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                </label>
            </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

***.css**

```
.review-summary-table tbody td label input {
    display: none;
}

// default
.review-summary-table tbody td label input + .fa {
    color: #E6E6E6;
}

// hover, clicked, ...
.review-summary-table tbody td label:hover input + .fa,
.review-summary-table tbody td label input:checked + .fa,
.review-summary-table tbody td.active label input + .fa,
.review-summary-table tbody tr:hover td.tmp-active label input + .fa {
    color: #50A4CF;
}
```

***.js**

```
var reviewTable = $('#product-review-table');

if (reviewTable.length > 0) {
    reviewTable.each(function() {
        $(this).find('tbody tr').each(function() {
            var row = $(this),
                tdValues = row.find('td.value');

            tdValues.each(function(index) {
                $(this).find('label').hover(function() {
                    tdValues.removeClass('tmp-active');

                    tdValues.slice(0, index + 1).addClass('tmp-active');
                }).click(function() {
                    tdValues.removeClass('active');

                    tdValues.slice(0, index + 1).addClass('active');
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: i followed your solution, now is displaying like this : `http://prntscr.com/bpsz73` but i can not able to select `staars` , you can check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/vintage-retro-bicycle-background-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) & than click on `Add review` tab.